# Добавление наследника вместо базового класса в emplace_back приводит к ошибке C2243

Tags: c++, наследование, вектор

```
#include <vector>

class A {};

class C {
public:
    C(A*);
};

class B : A {
    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::vector<C> v;
        v.emplace_back(this);
    }
};
```

Пытаюсь добавить в вектор некоторый класс, который ожидает указатель на базовый класс в конструкторе, передавая ему наследника. Если использовать `push_back`, то всё работает. При `emplace_back` же возникает ошибка:

> error C2243: 'type cast': conversion from '_Ty' to 'A *' exists, but
> is inaccessible

В чём причина этой ошибки? Как исправить?

Comment: Используйте `public` наследование или приводите к указателю на `A` явно.

Comment: @user7860670 а почему возникает ошибка при emplace_back, но нет ошибки при push_back?

Comment: Ошибка возникает потому что при `emplace_back` преобразование указателя на `B` в указатель на `A` будет осуществляться внутри функции `emplace_back`. А при `push_back` - внутри функции `DoSomething`, при неявном создании временного экземпляра `С` (что происходит из-за другой ошибки - конструктор `C` объявлен как `implicit`.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте `public` в объявление наследования

```
class B : public A {
```

Полный код: https://ideone.com/R6w3iK

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/807297)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics Вы по ссылке-то переходили? :) Сразу видно, что нет. Там не ответ, а полный текст на ideone... И уж эти-то ссылки никогда "ответом по ссылке" не рассматривались :)

Comment: Правила не запрещают публикацию внешних ссылок, но в данном виде ответ без перехода по ссылке не понятен.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics Предельно понятен: добавить в наследование `public`...